# Is it possible to add a third parameter to an autocomplete textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using the code below to populate an ajax autocomplete textbox using the last name and selected state. So if a user types "Jones" it will populate all the rows where last name is like "Jones". Is it possible to add another parameter so the user can type "Jones, John"? So it will also lookup the ", John" ? Thanks!

```
Public Function GetCompletionList(prefixText As String, count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
    Try
        Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Con = New SqlConnection
        Dim test As String
        test = contextKey
        Con.ConnectionString = ""
        Con.Open()

        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = Con
        'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)], [Provider First Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] FROM NPIData WHERE [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] LIKE @Provider + '%' AND [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] = @State"
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)], [Provider First Name],[Provider First Line Business Mailing Address], [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code] FROM NPIData WHERE     ([Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] = @State) AND ([Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%') ORDER BY [Provider First Name]"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provider", prefixText)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", contextKey)
        Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        While reader.Read
            customers.Add(reader("Provider Last Name (Legal Name)").ToString + ", " + reader("Provider First Name").ToString + "   " + reader("Provider First Line Business Mailing Address").ToString + "  " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address City Name").ToString + ", " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address State Name").ToString + "  " + reader("Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code").ToString + "  " + reader("NPI").ToString)

        End While


        Con.Close()

        Return customers.ToArray
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: just split the input by comma and tweek your query accordingly. no need to pass third parameter.

Comment: Are you wanting to `AND` the two values together? In other words, if the user types in "Jones, John", then you are expecting it should return all rows where `Last Name` = "Jones" AND all rows where `First Name` = "John"?

Comment: Right, I agree with @Zia, but you are going to have to make it clear in your UI that a comma separated value applies to different columns, if that is in fact what you want to happen. It complicates the UI.

Comment: Yes, I would like the list to filter by the first name as well so when they type "Jones, J" it will start filtering by all first names starting with J

Comment: Do I do something like this? AND ([Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] AND [Provider First Name] LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%') ORDER BY [Provider First Name]"  How do filter out the ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GetCompletionList` function you need to split the incoming `prefixText` string, like this:

```
' Split prefixText string by commas
Dim words As String() = prefixText.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

Now you can tweak your `SQL` by referencing the pieces of the string, like this:

```
words(0) = Last Name
words(1) = First Name
```

Comment: I changed my SQL statement to the following but I am getting the error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NPI, [Entity Type Code], [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)], [Provider First Name],[Provider First Line Business Mailing Address], [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name], [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code] FROM NPIData WHERE     ([Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] = @State) AND ('" & words(0) & "','" & words(1) & "' LIKE N'%' + @Provider + N'%') ORDER BY [Provider First Name]"

Comment: Your syntax is wrong where you are using `words(0)` and `words(1)`. I suggest breaking the `SQL` into two queries and getting the results working before trying to combine them into one query.

Comment: I would also suggest moving this to a new question, as it is now a `SQL` question and not a code question. Feel free to accept an answer if it helped you.